# how to write a correlated query in hive

Tags: hive

can anyone please suggest how we can implement a correlated query in hive.

in SQL i am able to write but when i tried the same in hive it giving a error.

SQL query for reference

```
SELECT M.MODELNAME,(SELECT SALE FROM CAR WHERE MONTH='Jan' AND    MODELID=M.MODELID) AS JAN_SALE,(SELECT SALE FROM CAR WHERE MONTH='Feb' AND     MODELID=M.MODELID) AS FEB_SALE,(SELECT SALE FROM CAR WHERE MONTH='Mar' AND     MODELID=M.MODELID) AS MAR_SALE FROM MODEL M INNER JOIN CAR C     ON(C.MODELID=M.MODELID);
```

Please suggest.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.MODELID,
M.MODELNAME,
C.MONTH,
SUM(C.SALE) as SUM_SALE
```

FROM MODEL M INNER 
    JOIN CAR C ON C.MODELID=M.MODELID
GROUP By M.MODELID, M.MODELNAME, C.MONTH

Comment: thanks for great answer,  but what I was looking for a single row having sale for different month for each model in output result.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Kim

but what i exactly want is in below format

MODELNAME | JAN_SALE | FEB_SALE  | MAR_SALE

your query is giving 9 rows in output but my requirement is a single line for each model

i tried to write a query for the same, please review n suggest if it is good to be used or will it cause any performance issues?

hive> select distinct m.modelname,e.sale jan_sale,e2.sale feb_sale,e3.sale mar_sale from (select * from car where month='JAN') e join car c on(e.modeid=c.modeid) join (select * from car where month='FEB') e2 on(c.modeid=e2.modeid) join (select * from car where month='MAR') e3 on (c.modeid=e3.modeid) join model m on (c.modeid=m.modelid);

result is :

Audi    20.0    21.0    30.0

Duster  20.0    21.0    30.0

Maruti  12.0    13.0    16.0